# Are you allowed to re-assign char* to a string literal?

Tags: c++

This is quite normal:

```
[const] char *str = "some text";
```

But initialisation is not the same as reassignment and string literals are a bit of a special case. What are the rules if you try to do this:

```
[const] char *str = "some text";
str = "some other text";
```

**Note** before someone says "try it" I'm asking what the language spec says, not what my particular compiler does.

Answer (score 3):

Let's repose your question as being assignment and reassignment to a `const char*`. This is because a string literal is a read-only array of characters terminated will `\0`, and compilers are lapse in allowing assignment of a string literal to a `char*`. C++11 explicitly forbids this.

Reassignment of a `const char*` to a different literal is permissible: there is no danger of a memory leak here since the strings will be stored in a read-only section of your compiled binary.

Comment: "This is because a string literal is a read-only array of characters terminated will `nullptr`", nope.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realised `const char*` _could_ be reassigned.

Comment: It is *not* terminated by `nullptr`. It it terminated by the ANSI character code representing 'null'.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error! Of course it's `\0`. `nullptr` is never to be confused with a zero. I'm not a perfect cat.

Answer (score 2):

#### About `char*`

As of C++11 all of that code is illegal. String literals can only be binded to `char const*` or in general a `[char] const` array.

Notice that a `char[]` can be initialized with a string literal as per §8.5.2/1:

> An array of narrow character type (3.9.1), `char16_t` array, `char32_t` array, or `wchar_t` array can be initialized by a narrow string literal, `char16_t` string literal, `char32_t` string literal, or wide string literal, respectively, or by an appropriately-typed string literal enclosed in braces (2.13.5). Successive characters of the value of the string literal initialize the elements of the array.
>
> [Example:
>
> ```
> char msg[] = "Syntax error on line %s\n";
> ```
>
> shows a character array whose members are initialized with a string-literal. [...]

Previously `char*` was supported but considered deprecated. And anyway, modifications to the string via that `char*` were considered undefined behaviour.

As per §4.2/2 (pre-C++11):

> A string literal (2.13.4) that is not a wide string literal can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to `char`”; a wide string literal can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to `wchar_t`”. In either case, the result is a pointer to the first element of the array. This conversion is considered only when there is an explicit appropriate pointer target type, and not when there is a general need to convert from an lvalue to an rvalue. [Note: this conversion is deprecated. See Annex D. ] For the purpose of ranking in overload resolution (13.3.3.1.1), this conversion is considered an array-to-pointer conversion followed by a qualification conversion (4.4). [Example: `"abc"` is converted to “pointer to `const char`” as an array-to-pointer conversion, and then to “pointer to `char`” as a qualification conversion. ]

### About reassigning the pointer

Reassinging a `char*` or a `char const*` is perfectly fine. The `const` there refers to the character, not the pointer. To avoid reassigning you would need `char* const` and `char const* const` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. We're working in VS 2013 but maybe we disabled that for backwards compatibility with our older code-base when we upgraded compiler. Probably I'll move to std::string (surely someone will tell me to!) but pre C++11 I'd still be interested.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it would be correctly to write

```
const char *str = "some text";
^^^^^
```

because string literals in C++ have types of constant character arrays. For example string literal "some text" has type `const char [10]`.

An array name used in expressions is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.

For example in this declaration

```
const char *str = "some text";
```

the string literal is implicitly converted to an object of type `const char *` and has value of the address of the first character of the string literal.

Pointers may be reassigned. The assignment operator may be used with pointers.

So you may write

```
const char *str = "some text";
str = "some other text";
```

Now pointer str is reassigned and points to to the first character of string literal "some other text".

However if you declare the pointer itself as a constant object as for example

```
const char * const str = "some text";
             ^^^^^
```

then in this case you may not reassigned it. The compiler will issue an error for statement

```
str = "some other text";
```